# Convert a byte to something human-readable

Tags: windows, sed, null, binary-data, type-conversion

I've got a file consisting of a bunch of 'rows' of data (not actually on separate lines). As far as I can tell from [the description <sub>(PDF)</sub>](http://www.nyxdata.com/doc/162153), each 'row' has forty bytes precisely, as follows:

- 4 bytes I can ignore.
- 2 bytes that are the byte representations of the (decimal) integer 240 or 241 — that is, 00 F0 or 00 F1 — depending on 'row'.
- 4 bytes I can ignore.
- 11 bytes: the first few bytes are an ASCII string, which I need, and the rest is padding by 00 bytes.
- 1 byte I can ignore.
- 1 byte I need. This seems from the documentation to be ASCII 'B', 'S', or '0'.
- 1 byte that's the byte representation of a small integer — that is, 00, 01, or the like.
- 4 bytes that are the byte representation of an integer.
- 4 bytes that are the byte representation of an integer.
- 4 bytes that are the byte representation of an integer.
- 4 bytes that are the byte representation of an integer.

And there's nothing else in the file (no file header, for example). (I may well be wrong in my understanding of the linked-to documentation, and would appreciate any correction; more info may be available [elsewhere <sub>(PDF)</sub>](http://www.nyxdata.com/doc/5977).)

I wish to:

1. **convert each byte representation of a number to a human-readable representation of the number and each 00 byte to (say) a human-readable 0**, and
2. convert the file to comma-separated or the like.

Now, step (2) should be doable using sed; I mention it only because I want to make sure step (1) is done is such a manner as to allow step (2) (for example, keep track of how many bytes are each field when doing step (1)). But step (1) I have no idea how to do. Can anyone help?

As a caveat, please note that I'm comfortable with sed and bash and can handle perl, but have no experience with real programming; and that, alas, I'm doing this on a Windows machine I don't have installation-of-programs rights on, so (although I have [a sed port](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)) I don't have bash. So, basically, **I need to do this in sed or a Windows (DOS) command-line script**. (I should be able to download the files to another machine, work with them, and upload them, though, if that turns out to be necessary.)

Comment: if you don't have a unix tool kit to work with, you won't be able to get sed to read NUL chars (i.e. \000). If you can pipe your file thru `od` (with the apropriate arguments), then you have a chance. Yes, I think perl can do this OR you can write a simple c program (with required compilation of course). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter The Windows port of sed claims to handle 8-bit characters okay (though I haven't tested that claim yet). I don't know about 00 specifically, though. `'od' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` (And thanks for the good wishes! `:-)`)

Comment: yes, your 11 byte ASCII padded with '00's will be a problem (unless 8 bit char processing includes the NUL). My experience is that it doesn't but the only way to be sure is to do the minimal experiments to prove or disprove your hypothesis. You might also see if there is any support either from the author of your windows sed, or a dedicated mail group or other. Again, good luck!

Comment: Write a quick c# program using bit converter. Why struggling with sed that seems to be causing so much headache. Anyone could get a program to solve this up and running in less than an hour in C#. By all means use whatever language you feel comfortable but you currently seem to want to try to plant orange trees in the Antarctica.

Comment: @Freddy, yes, if I knew C# and had a compiler for it. The first is false and I think the second is also. I do like your analogy, though.

Comment: After consulting with someone offline (and from the above comments), it looks as though [this `od`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) is the way to go...

Answer (score 1):

Perl has an [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) function you could use.

Comment: Ah, thank you. (I haven't got the 15 rep to upvote you, though.)

Comment: @msh210: you have 15 rep now. :)  And if this answered your question, it helps others if you indicate that by clicking the green check mark.